How to pass a String parameter to a viewmodel in compose?
How can I pass a String parameter to a ViewModel in Compose? I mean a string variable, not a hardcoded one or an Application stored one. I need to pass it as a parameter. This is just for learning purposes, now it is a String but tomorrow can be a custom object for example.
In the codelabs they explain how to pass parameters than can be generated using Application, like this:
companion object {
        val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                MyViewModel(
                    MyApplication().container.repository
                )
            }
        }
    }

And later using that companion object variable like this:
viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(factory = MyViewModel.factory)

But they don't explain how to pass a simple String parameter. How can I adapt that code for receiving a String as a parameter and passing it when initializing the viewModel?
I tried what CommonsWare suggested, and obviously it doesn't compile, something is missing in the explanation. How can I pass myString variable? I just want to transform that factory to receive a String variable, but don't know how to achieve it.
companion object {
        val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                LoadingScreenViewModel(
                    myString
                )
            }
        }
    }


Replace MyApplication().container.repository with your string variable, and have MyViewModel() take a String parameter. This makes me think that I am misunderstanding your question. Could you please post a [mcve] showing what you tried and explaining what problems you encountered? If your concern is that factory is a property on a companion object, that is not a requirement. And, if your concern is how this interacts with your dependency inversion framework, which one are you using?

@CommonsWare I don't know what I'm explaning bad. I attached to the question what you suggested, switching the repo with a String parameter, and I don't know how to make it compile. Please, can you help me? The viewmodel already takes a String as a parameter, but in the companion object I need to pass that string and I don't know how to do it. On the other hand, I'm not using any inversion framework, it's a simple project for learning how to pass parameter to a viewmodel without using third party libraries, just with a factory and a companion object

Option 1: Use a function
companion object {
        fun factory(myString: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                LoadingScreenViewModel(
                    myString
                )
            }
        }
    }

Option 2: Do not use a companion object, but instead initialize the factory at the point where you need it
        val myString: String = TODO() // fill in logic to get your string value
        val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                LoadingScreenViewModel(
                    myString
                )
            }
        }

Option 3: Use your preferred dependency inversion framework (Dagger/Hilt, Koin, etc.) and avoid creating your own factory

thank you so much ! It compiles, don't have time to try it but I think now I understand everything. I'll try to make it work soon. Thanks

Viewmodels are needed to be initialized using a factory, the code mentioned in the companion object does its job but there is a better way of making a viewModelFactory.
Here is a example, basically a boiler plate code and copy paste it as per your need.

By Creating a Seprate ViewModelFactory class and making appropriate declarations.

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MyViewModelFactory(
    private val someString1: String,
    private val someString2: String,
    private val someString3: String
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        
        // Change the ViewModel Class Name Below
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) { 
            return MyViewModel(someString1, someString2, someString3) as T // Add the values to the MyViewModel constructor
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}


Using companion object in a ViewModel

   companion object{
        // Declaring a variable factory and initializing variables inside lambda function viewModelFactory.
        val factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val someString = "some_string"
                MyViewModel(someString)
            }
        }

        // Declaring a function with constructors and with a similar approach as the above factory declaration.
        fun factory(someString: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                MyViewModel(someString)
            }
        }
    }


Dependency Injection


Hi, maybe can it be done with the companion object I suggested? can you please offer an alternative more similar to the one I posted? using companion object I mean. Please, don't delete this option, will consider it if is not possible to achieve it with companion object

Sure that can be, I'll update the answer in sometime.
